# Access sys/select.h while in a DKM in VxWorks

Tags: kernel-module, vxworks, wind-river-workbench

I am running an application that is a DKM in VxWorks. I have functions that need the sys/select.h file, however that is only available to RTPs. Is there a way to access those function in a DKM?

Comment: It is better to specify which exact functions you need. It could be that `sys/select.h` header cannot be accessible for your configuration, but there are replacement for functions you need. Or it could be that part of functions from `sys/select.h` could be accessible through other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create same file inside VSB for kernel.
i.e. $VSB_DIR/krnl/h/public/sys/select.h
and copy the contents from $VSB_DIR/user/h/public/sys/select.h.